# Pattern matching on deque

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, deque

I'm trying to do some pattern matching on deque in haskell, but have some problems.

Here is some explanation for what i'm trying to do.

I'm trying to implement a compiler from Refal to Haskell. Refal is a language that uses pattern matching alot. So a typical refal function looks like this:

```
    RefalFunc {
         e.1 s.1 (e.2) 's' t.1 t.2 t.1 e.2 = e.1 e.2
         e.1 ' ' e.2 = 'foo' e.1 'foo' e.2
         e.1 = 'anyexpression'
    }
```

So this function takes an refal-expression (which consists of terms) and try to match it with 1 of 3 patterns, and if it succeeded then transform refal-expression into another according to rules on the right side.

e.1, e.2 .. - means some refal-expressions
t.1 t.2 - means some terms , for example "(e.1 t.2 e.2)" is a term, "e.1 t.2 e.2" is not 
s.A s.1   - means symbols
's' - means symbol 's'. there are some others type of symbols, but it doesn't matter.

In my compiler refal-expressions represent as deques, so for each refal function i need to generate a function, which takes some deque and transform it, according to some pattern. 
So i have something like this

```
    myFunc1:: Deque -> Deque
    myFunc1 deq = if matchPattern1 deq then doSomeWork1
                  else if matchPattern2 deq then doSomeWork2
                  ...
               where matchPattern1 = ...
                     matchPattern2 = ...
                     ....
```

So, the main problem is, that I'm realy don't know how to do that matchPattern functions.

So, for given deque I can easily find first(or last) term or symbol, but i'm don't know what to do, when i meet e.1, which means part of the deque with uknown size.

So here's example.
Deque: ( 5 + 6 ) * 7 * ( 5 + ( 4 + 1 ) ) * ( 5 + 6 ) * ( 5 + 6 ) //every symbol here is an element of the deque, every non-Bracket symbol is a term, every (/*some symbols*/) is a term

I need to check is this deque match the following patterns (and find an appropriate partition)

```
 pattern1: t.1 e.1 t.1
 pattern2: t.1 '*' e.1 (t.2 e.2) s.1 t.1 e.3
```

answer for pattern1 :

```
 t.1 = ( 5 + 6 )
 e.1 =  * 7 * ( 5 + ( 4 + 1 ) ) * ( 5 + 6 ) *
```

answer for pattern2 :

```
 t.1 =  ( 5 + 6 )
 e.1 = 7 *
 t.2 = 5
 s.1 = *
 e.2 = + ( 4 + 1 )  
 e.3 =  * ( 5 + 6 )
```

I'm using an implementation of Okasaki CatenableDeque.

Comment: Isn't Okasaki's `Deque` a class?

Comment: in my example Deque is a type: 
type Deque = ImplicitCatDeque BankersDeque VfElement , 
where ImplicitCatDeque and BankersDeque is my implemenation of Okasaki's Data Structures (I took it from his book) . VfELement is my data to represent an Element of refal-expression.  So I have following functions on my Deque: head, tail, cons, snoc, init, last, (++), size

Comment: It looks like you need a generic (not character-based) extended regular expression matcher.